# Mechanical turk: External question not working from requester interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

Is it possible to use the external question tag (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html) from the AWS requester interface? I've tried, but it gives me a form error. Adding a form or crowd form "fixes" the issue, but the site is still missing. Is it possible to use XML (aside from the crowd-form elements) on the editor? Below is an image of external question embedded in a crowd-form tag and the result.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible.

If you are comfortable sharing more details about your use case we may be able to suggest workarounds.

If you prefer to discuss privately, please contact us at https://support.aws.amazon.com/#/contacts/aws-mechanical-turk.

Comment: I'm trying to host an external website on AMT without going through AWS (which would require AWS accounts and keys) or using a survey link (it requires users navigate to the site, copy a code and AFAIK limits users to one survey). Is there a way to use my website, but keep the convenience of a "native" HIT?

Comment: You can use an external survey link with the unique code technique using the Survey Link template on the Requester website without needing to set up an AWS account.

These blog posts share more details:

https://blog.mturk.com/getting-started-with-surveys-on-mturk-e2eea524c73

https://blog.mturk.com/editing-the-survey-link-project-template-in-the-ui-7c75285105fb?gi=e10e8d5b9876

https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-getting-great-survey-results-from-mturk-and-surveymonkey-f49c2891ca6f

https://blog.mturk.com/getting-great-survey-results-from-mturk-and-qualtrics-be1704ff9786

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, I would like to avoid that if possible. Is there no other way?